# How to find second maximum temperature using Secondary Sort in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In Secondary sorting example year and temperature. We take year and temperature as a composite key. And print the first key,value pair to print the maximum temperature of that year.

> 1900 35°C
>   1900 34°C
>   1900 34°C
>  
>   ...
>  
>   1901 36°C
>  
>   1901 35°C

```
protected void reduce(IntPair key, Iterable<NullWritable> values,
Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    context.write(key, NullWritable.get());
}
```

Now if we want to print second maximum for a particular year how can we do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way this is setup you can't do this, the `temperature` also needs to be set as the value, so your `reduce` method signature would need to change to something like:

```
protected void reduce(IntPair key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ...
}
```

The objective with a secondary sort is to use a composite key to sort the **values** so having a `NullWritable` as the value is going to stop this from working. Once you have the temperature in the value you can iterate through them and ignore the first value, thus getting the second maximum. For example:

```
protected void reduce(IntPair key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    boolean first = true;
    for (IntWritable temp : values) {
        if (!first) {
            context.write(key, temp);
            return;
        } else {
            first = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now that the temperature is in the values you can just iterate through them, ignore the first one, write out the second and exit.

Note: This code assumes there aren't duplicate temperatures.